# Solr Error Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field id

Tags: solr

While Importing the data into Solr using DataImportHandler, I am getting the below error. Please someone provide your suggestion.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id
        at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getIndexedId(AddUpdateCommand.java:92)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:717)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:557)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:70)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:235)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:512)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:416)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:331)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:239)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:411)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:483)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:464)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of your input and import code.

Comment: Like it says: the `id` field is mandatory (but does not exist or might be empty). Add an id field before posting the document to the solr server.

Answer (score 6):

In the `schema.xml` file you have mentioned id as required `field = true`.

Also the document that you are trying to index in SOLR do not contain this id field and hence SOLR is throwing this error.

### Solution

1. Either add id to all your documents

OR

2. Remove `required = true` form schema file for id field.

Please share your `schema.xml` file and the documents that you are trying to index into SOLR.

Also keep in mind if you want quick response try to provide as much details as you can.

Answer (score 1):

this is probably where the error reporting should be improved for `solr`

for my case, I've defined a `string field` not related with `KEY`, and I am trying to put a `null` value to that field. I should probably indicate the field is `nullable`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and the reason was in my data import configuration. If you are using a hsqldb connection to import your data, pay attention to the way you map the database columns to your solr fields. **Hsqldb is case sensitive.** So, for example, the following was producing an error.

```
<field column="item_id" name="id" />
```

While this is working perfectly:

```
<field column="ITEM_ID" name="id" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue whereby I either had nulls or duplicates in the id field.

Check that there are no duplicates in your id field with:

```
SELECT MAX(c) FROM (SELECT COUNT(x) as c, if FROM TABLE GROUP BY id)
```

And check the response is = 1. If not, you can find the fields with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c, id FROM <table> GROUP BY id HAVING c > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, even if everything was working fine.
I created new SolrDocument in each loop while indexing.

```
HttpSolrServer server =
      new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/shard1");
Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs = new ArrayList<>();

for (list<String> data: datas) {
  
    SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
    String id = data("id");
    String fileName = data("fileName");
    String column2 = data("column2");
    String column3 = data("column3");

    i++;
    doc.addField("id", id);
    doc.addField("title", fileName);
    doc.addField("size", getFileSizeInMb(fileEntry.length()));
    doc.addField("column2", column2);
    doc.addField("column3", column3);

    System.out.println("doc: " + doc);
    docs.add(doc);
    
    if (i % 100 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Committed :" + i);
        server.add(docs);
        docs.clear();
    }  
}
server.commit();
```

initializing this in each loop made my code work

```
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
```